# How to store values of a text box into external SQL database table on button click in MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC.

I have no clue how I am going to connect and store values in text box on a view on button click into sql table.

Please help

Comment: It sounds like what you need is to walk through some ASP.NET MVC tutorials.  The NerdDinner tutorial is a popular one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/nerddinner/introducing-the-nerddinner-tutorial  Essentially the page would post the form value(s) to a controller action.  That action would assemble a model and interact with it in some way (possibly instructing it to persist to a data store).  Ultimately the action would return a view or in some way result in a view being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Given the level that you are starting from I suggest you read the excellent tutorial series on the [Microsoft Asp MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Also searching with your favourite search engine for "MVC3 tutorials" will help as well.